# Print "available method" telegram API Ruby in message

Tags: ruby, bots, telegram

This is very noob, but I'm still very interested.
I'm using Ruby to develop telegram bot. https://github.com/atipugin/telegram-bot-ruby - this is my wrapper for this.

I have code:

```
bot.api.get_Chat_Members_Count(chat_id: message.chat.id)
```

I want to present a result in text in:

```
bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Results: %")
```

How can I link result of this method and print in into text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.api.get_chat_members_count(chat_id: message.chat.id)` returns hash in format `{"ok"=>true, "result"=>8}`

So you need use key for this:

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    if message.text == '/start'
      count = bot.api.get_chat_members_count(chat_id: message.chat.id)['result']
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Result: #{count}")
    end
  end
end
```